# Image map not working

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have an image map and my link is not clickable on my image. Here is my map/image code:

```
<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="208, 76, 229, 101" href="link here">
</map>
<img id="himg" usemap="#map" src="img here">
```

Here is "himg" css:

```
#himg {
    position:relative;
    width:781px;
    height:245px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index: -10;
    }
```

At first I had the image before the map, but then switched it so the  map comes first, but that did not make anything clickable.

Comment: Why do you have a negative z-index?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhzvpg4u/. Remove `z-index` like @jo8691 said

Comment: I need the z-index - however, I was able to remove the position element without it affecting the layout. I don't know why I didn't try that out before... *facepalm* Thanks guys!